# Get Unix timestamp from 'n/j Y' date PHP

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

I have a date in 'n/j Y' format and would like to get a timestamp. The following code returns 1513109760, which is incorrect. It's a timestamp for 12/12 2017.

```
$date = '12/12 2016';
echo $date. ', ' .strtotime($date);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$date = '12/12 2016';
$datetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j Y', $date);
$datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to present the date to `strtotime` in a format it can understand. So either amend the format like this.

If day month and year is seperated by a `/` then US date format is assumed i.e. MM/DD/YYYYY.

If they are seperated by a `-` then a European format is assumes i.e. DD-MM-YYYYY

```
$date = '12/12 2016';
$fixed = str_replace(array(' ', '/'), '-', $date);
echo strtotime($fixed);
echo PHP_EOL;
echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fixed));
```

Alternatively use the DateTime Object

```
$date = '12/12 2016';
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('n/j Y', $date);
echo $dt->getTimestamp();
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option is to use a regular expression to extract the date components, then use [mktime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) to create the timestamp.

```
$date = '12/12 2016';

preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)/', $date, $dateParts);

$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0, $dateParts[0][0], $dateParts[0][1], $dateParts[0][2]);

echo $timestamp;
```

**Result:**

```
1481500800
```